# How to resolve cycle Gradle rule based model configuration

Tags: gradle

I am trying to create a plugin uses Gradle's rule based model configuration. The plugin should do the following:

- Add some custom Jar tasks
- Add these Jar tasks to the archives configuration
- Add all Jar tasks from the archives configuration to a Maven publication

This however introduces a circular dependency in the model rules:

```
tasks ==> MavenPublishPlugin.Rules#realizePublishingTasks ==> configurations ==> tasks
```

Is there a way around this?

Regards,
Jochen

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this please?  This looks very similar to the problem I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911241/gradle-how-to-create-maven-publication-from-inside-rule-block

Comment: No viable solution yet. I reverted to creating these configurations and tasks when initializing the plugin (before the model rules are evaluated) and then later configure them using model rules.